# How to check if a post has at least 2 terms from a custom taxonomy attached?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy with several terms. I need to check if the post has more than 1 of these terms. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_the_terms( int|object $post, string $taxonomy ).
```

Use the above function to get the terms of the taxonomy. It will return the array of terms associated with the post. Then you can use the php function

```
$count = count( $array ).
```

it will return the count of the terms. After getting the count use the if statement

```
if( $count > 1) { //do what you want }.
```